# Carrierwave and rails fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minitest

How would I use populate rails fixtures(yaml) with carrierwave uploads?
The documentation doesn't seem to cover this and the carrierwave wiki does not either.

I have tried

and I have verified that the above ruby code generates a valid file object.

Comment: Fixtures aren't covered any more in Ruby on Rails documentation because they are discouraged. More effective ways of creating initial data exist, such as factories. See [FactoryGirl](http://github.comthoughtbot/factory_girl)

Comment: Well Rails 4 still comes bundled with fixtures. Are you saying there is a divide between the documentation writers and the framework devs?

Comment: I'm not privy to the reason it's still bundled, backwards-compatibility, I suppose? Search Google for "rails fixtures vs factories" and you'll see the community consensus is to not use fixtures. See [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/992304/695772)

Comment: There isn't a consensus as fixtures and factories were designed to handle different tasks. Fixtures are "raw" data inserted into test database before every spin up. They are the seed in test env, the starting point. Factories are best used to create scenario-specific db entries when needed, they are slower and operate under different transaction rules. I myself been using factories to populate entire test suite for years only to switch back to fixtures. You can still use both in a project, but it's rare. If only fixtures weren't still limited to prehistoric YAML with terrible ERB support...

Answer (score 0):

I doubt fixtures are going anywhere as they are used exclusively in the Rails codebase itself. Plus i use them, so that is all that matters.

I also found this [article](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2014/using-test-fixtures-with-carrierwave/) that helped me, and also you.

Boiled down in `test_helper.rb`

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  CarrierWave.root = Rails.root.join('test/fixtures/files') #path is up to you
  def after_teardown
    super
    CarrierWave.clean_cached_files!(0)
  end
end

class CarrierWave::Mount::Mounter
  def store!
   # Not storing uploads in the tests
  end
end
```

I then put in my uploader:

```
def store_dir
  if Rails.env.test?
    "images"
  else
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

I'm sure i can get rid of the need for that `store_dir` ternary like statement, but for now it works. I've got another way if this doesn't do work for you, but this is cleaner.